# Got an error using MultilayerPerceptronClassifier: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(OneHotEncoderModel$$Lambda

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I tried excluding all null values and make my label starts from '0' instead of '1'. Both don't solve the error. The error says failed to execute OneHotEncoder, but I am not using it in my code.. Followings are my code and the error I got.

This is my DataFrame. I dropped all null values.

```
low_ask_sizes:integer
ask_price:integer
collaboration:integer
released_months:integer
brand:string
cate_color:string
label:integer
```

Split the data into train and test

```
train, validation, test = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.2, 0.1], 1234)
```

Convert nominal column to numerical column

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

categorical_columns = [item[0] for item in data.dtypes if item[1].startswith('string')]
numeric_columns = [item[0] for item in data.dtypes if item[1].startswith('int')]
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol='{0}_index'.format(
    column), handleInvalid = 'keep') for column in categorical_columns]
```

Assemble feature columns into one feature vector column

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

featuresCreator = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[indexer.getOutputCol() for indexer in indexers] + numeric_columns,
    outputCol='features')
layers = [len(featuresCreator.getInputCols()), 4, 2, 2]
```

Select features (vector column) and label column

```
prepared_data = output.select('features', 'label')
```

This is the structure of prepared_data:

```
features:udt
label:integer
```

Classifier

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

classifier = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(labelCol='label',
                                            featuresCol='features',
                                            maxIter=100,
                                            layers=layers,
                                            blockSize=128,
                                            seed=1234)
```

Build the pipeline and start training the model

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + [featuresCreator, classifier])
model = pipeline.fit(train)
```

It gives me this error on the last line:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2394554338211359> in <module>
      2 
      3 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + [featuresCreator, classifier])
----> 4 model = pipeline.fit(train)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    112                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    113                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 114                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    115                     transformers.append(model)
    116                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 335         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    336         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    337         return self._copyValues(model)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    330         """
    331         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 332         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    108     def deco(*a, **kw):
    109         try:
--> 110             return f(*a, **kw)
    111         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    112             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3766.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 773.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 773.0 (TID 1010) (ip-10-172-226-106.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(OneHotEncoderModel$$Lambda$6652/897874937: (double, int) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It's not possible to reproduce the error from your description. Provide sample data please

Comment: please also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: I had the same problem when my label wasn't ordered, like, distinct values were: 0, 2, 4
When I made my target to have the distinct values like: 0, 1, 3, it worked fine